# angular controller communication with a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to communicate controllers with another.

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);

module.service("MessageAggregator", function(){
    var service = {};

    service.message = {};

    service.setMessage = function(message){
        service.message = message;
    };

    return service;
    });

    function firstController($scope, MessageAggregator){
        $scope.sendRequest = function(){
            MessageAggregator.setMessage({type: "FeatureSet"});
        };
    }

    function secondController($scope, MessageAggregator){
        $scope.info = MessageAggregator;
        $scope.message = MessageAggregator.message;
    }
```

I want to use MessageAggregator service data in html view.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="firstController">
        <button ng-click="sendRequest()">Request</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-controller="secondController">
         <h3>info: {{info}}</h3>
         <h3>message: {{message}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working code is [here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/vGqCp/1/)

```
<h3>message: {{message}}</h3>  not populated and working
<h3>info: {{info}}</h3> is working
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your controller in your module

```js
module.controller("firstController", function($scope, MessageAggregator){
    $scope.sendRequest = function(){
        MessageAggregator.setMessage({type: "FeatureSet"});
    };
});

module.controller("secondController", function($scope, MessageAggregator){
    $scope.info = MessageAggregator;
    $scope.message = MessageAggregator.message;
});
```

Comment: what is the difference? I tried in jsfiddle but same result.

Comment: Sorry I think I can't answer your question. @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy 's way may work but I think it's too complecated. I suggest replace `<h3>message: {{message}}</h3>` to `<h3>message: {{info.message}}</h3>`, leave the binding/ watching thing to angular

Comment: I guess after setMessage(), the $scope.message in secondController is still reference to the old one

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitely add watch listener for `MessageAggregator.message` object:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return MessageAggregator.message; },
  function(newVal, oldVal) { $scope.message = newVal; });
```

Here is an [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTeI5uqnqGtAmWkNxDpq?p=preview)

or you should to change the `service.setMessage` function as below to preserve `message` object reference:

```
service.setMessage = function (message) {
    for (var prop in message) {
        if (message.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            service.message[prop] = message[prop];
        }

        for(var prop in service.message){
            if(!message.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                delete service.message[prop];
            }
        }
    }
};
```