# Angular JS pass parameter one controller to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I have two controllers in my app TimelineController and ReservationModalController. I want to call TimelineController from ReservationModalController and pass variable value. I'm trying to that:
this is my app.js

```
$stateProvider
// Timeline
    .state('timeline', {

    url: '/timeline',
    controller: 'TimelineController',
    templateUrl: 'assets/partials/timeline.html',
    params: {
        operation: 'false'
    }

})
```

this is TimelineController

```
$scope.operation = $state.current.params.operation;
```

and this is ReservationModalController :

```
$scope.edit = function() {
  $modalInstance.close();
  $state.go('timeline', {
    operation: 'true'
  });
};
```

At the first time variable is initialized. But when I click the button and ReservationModalController and it's method `edit` is called  TimelineController and it's variable `$scope.operation` does not change.

Please help me what is wrong?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842597/angular-controller-communication-with-a-service I'm guessing you want your controllers to be able to talk to each other.

Comment: I know this solution but in my case, i don't want to use this. In angular i can use $state.go() function but does not working, so i'm interesting why?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should `$broadcast` to communicate between controllers here so they are not as tightly bound to each other. `$rootScope.$broadcast` is sending an event through the application scope.
Any children scope of that app can catch it using a simple: `$scope.$on()`.

It is especially useful to send events when you want to reach a scope that is not a direct parent (like two controllers of which is none a parent for the other for example).

There's a fiddle that shows how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/VxafF/

Comment: Your script in my browser does not working. Also i know this solution but i don't want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try nesting your TimeLineController inside your ReservationModalController. That way you can use **$scope** inheritance to communicate between controllers.

Read this:http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/nestedcontrollers/